# Determine Dell model numbers for batches of computers by IP or Service Tag?

Tags: batch, dell-inspiron, dell-latitude, dell-optiplex

I have ~2000 computers that I'm trying to create a database for, and see what models these are. I have the Service Tags, and the IP addresses, and I can manually go in and run a remote System Information, but this is tedious and time consuming to do a new remote System Information for every individual PC.

Is there a way to identify the System Models of batches of computers?

Comment: WMI might help. Sadly, I know very little about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking with Dell Customer service I was able to find that you can upload a CSV file, get the information, and export the information again.

Go on Dell's Support page, hover over Support, select "My Products and Services" and sign up for an account. Once you have an account, and you go back to the "My Products and Services" page, select "Find and add products", Open and Upload the CSV file. This provides a list of all the service tags, models, date shipped, warranty type, and days left of warranty. Select "Add selected products", and move to the "Product List" tab, select all the items you want to export, and then in the "Actions" drop down, select "Export". Job done!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to run an inventory scan with an inventorying program, and it will return the system model information as well as other hardware/system information.

It would require port 445 to be open between the scanning computer and the remainder of the computers.

I'd recommend PDQ Inventory for the scan. The free version should suffice. It can be found here: https://www.pdq.com/pdq-inventory/